# Is it possible to wire a 120v light off of a 220v compressor?

Tags: electrical

I have a 60 gallon compressor in my shop that people leave running overnight, killing electricity.  I would like to wire a light off my compressor switch so it lights up when the compressor is on.  Would it be possible to wire it off a single hot, then use the ground and neutral?

Comment: Why not just use a timer - turns on at 08.00 and off at 18.00... because the lamp still requires them to look, register and act.

Comment: Are you married to incandescent bulbs?

Comment: Do you want this as a pilot light of sorts...?

Comment: Some of the newer led bulbs are 100-277 compatible use one of those and not energize your ground, but I would agree a timer may be a better plan.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about how to wire up a 120v bulb - just get one that is designed for 220v.  Half the world uses 220v for lighting and general purpose outlets, so it's not hard to find online.  If you want to find something in a local store, look closely at the boxes for LED bulbs.  They could have a power supply that supports a wide range for the global market.

If you want a certain type of bulb, look online.  You can find LED or incandescent with a variety of bases.

And to add in other answers from the comments - a timer might be a good choice for you.  Home stores commonly sell large mechanical timers for 220v water heaters.  They should work well on something like an air compressor (assuming it is less than 40A, larger timers might be more rare).

And of course the other option would be to fix all the air leaks so the compressor never runs.